# How to use radial gradient in Tailwindcss

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I'm trying to apply radial gradient in Tailwind but facing some issues. This's what I've tried `tailwind.config`

```
backgroundColor: {
  'radial-gradient': 'radial-gradient(169.40% 89.55% at 94.76% 6.29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%)',
},
```

and use it like

```
className='bg-radial-gradient'
```

This doesn't seem to work. How can I do this in Tailwind?

Comment: there are some good examples here: https://codepen.io/rishi111/pen/MWqOmxy

Answer (score 4):

As per [the MDN documentation on `radial-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient):

> The function's result is an object of the [`<gradient>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient) data type, which is a special kind of [`<image>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image).

`<image>`s are used in the [`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) property, so you'd add the value as a [`backgroundImage`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#customizing-your-theme) value in Tailwind:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'radial-gradient': 'radial-gradient(169.40% 89.55% at 94.76% 6.29%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.00) 100%)',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="bg-radial-gradient w-20 h-20"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to make mistakes configuring radial gradients manually, but unfortunately Tailwind doesn't provide utility classes for it at the moment (maybe because radial gradients are too diverse?). So I wrote a plugin for it.

## TL;DR

If your radial gradient is only used once, you can just inline it:

```
<section class="h-[20vh] w-screen bg-[radial-gradient(169.40%_89.55%_at_94.76%_6.29%,rgba(0,0,0,0.40)_0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.00)_100%)]"></section>
```

If you want to be more elegant：

1. Paste [this code](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aIdrzr64J3?file=config) into your config file
2. Usage:

```
<!-- Take op's example: -->
<section class="h-[20vh] w-screen bg-radient-[169.40%_89.55%_at_94.76%_6.29%] from-[#0006] to-transparent"></section>
<!-- Of course there are some presets: -->
<section class="h-[20vh] w-screen bg-radient-ellipse-c from-white from-0% to-black to-70%"></section>
```

## How does it work?

### Utilizing gradient stops

The definitions of linear and radial gradient stops are similar, and we can take advantage of this.

By inspecting the linear gradient css generated by tailwind, we see that the gradient stops are defined by `var(--tw-gradient-stops)`. With this, we can use utility classes such as `from-[color]`, `from-[percentage]`, etc.

like this:

```
<section class="h-[20vh] w-screen bg-[radial-gradient(ellipse_at_center,_var(--tw-gradient-stops))] from-white from-0% to-black to-70%"></section>
```

But using it inline is too verbose, we should convert it to a utility class.

### The plugin

For more elegant use, it's best to implement it as a plugin that:

1. Use the gradient stop variable
2. Support the use of arbitrary values to be more useful

```
const plugin = require('tailwindcss/plugin')

const radialGradientPlugin = plugin(
  function ({ matchUtilities, theme }) {
    matchUtilities(
      {
        // map to bg-radient-[*]
        'bg-radient': value => ({
          'background-image': `radial-gradient(${value},var(--tw-gradient-stops))`,
        }),
      },
      { values: theme('radialGradients') }
    )
  },
}
```

### Presets

But so far it only supports arbitrary values. We could add some commonly used presets.

Considering these preset definitions have similarities, it's too cumbersome to write the utility class definition by hand, so it's better to write a function to generate them:

```
const radialGradientPlugin = plugin(
  function ({ matchUtilities, theme })
      // ...
  },
  {
    theme: {
      radialGradients: _presets(),
    },
  }
)

function _presets() {
  const shapes = ['circle', 'ellipse'];
  const pos = {
    c: 'center',
    t: 'top',
    b: 'bottom',
    l: 'left',
    r: 'right',
    tl: 'top left',
    tr: 'top right',
    bl: 'bottom left',
    br: 'bottom right',
  };
  let result = {};
  for (const shape of shapes)
    for (const [posName, posValue] of Object.entries(pos))
      result[`${shape}-${posName}`] = `${shape} at ${posValue}`;

  return result;
}
```

You can add more presets as required. (either in the plugin or in the config file)

Click [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/aIdrzr64J3) for the full demo.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example (It's React code, but concept is general), I used clsx for gather classes (it's not necessary).

```
  <div className={clsx(
          'absolute h-[600px]  lg:h-[1100px] w-full right-0 top-0',
          'bg-[radial-gradient(ellipse_at_center_200px,_var(--tw-gradient-stops))]',
          'from-white/40 via-white/70 to-white to-[67%]',
          'dark:from-black/40 dark:via-black/70 dark:to-black dark:to-[67%]'
          )}>
  </div>
```

In `ellipse_at_center_200px` first one is x position and second one is y position.